# accessinig current pillar items in a loop from another template?

Tags: salt-stack

I have snippet like this in the init.sls:

```
{% for server, args in pillar.get('servers', {}).items() %}

software-server@{{ server }}
    service.running:
        - enable: true
        - require:
            - pkg: software_pkgs
        - watch:
            - file: software_config

/etc/software/{{server}}.json:
    file.managed:
        - source: salt://software/files/config.json.j2
        - template: jinja

{% endfor %}
```

config.json.j2:

```
{
  listen: {{server}}:{{listen_addr}}
}
```

and in the pillar:

```
software.servers:
  server1:
    listen_addr:10.0.0.1
  server2:
    listen_addr:127.0.01
```

in each of the {{server}}.json the `listen_addr` is different. I don't know if saltstack has something like a scope for current loop, or is there a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use context or defaults options in file.managed:

[file.managed](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed)

In your example it would like like :

```
/etc/software/{{server}}.json:
file.managed:
    - source: salt://software/files/config.json.j2
    - template: jinja
    - context:
      server: {{ server }}
      listen_addr: {{ server['listen_addr'] }}
```